# getting all the rows for the last minute in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, dataframe

How I can get all the rows added in the last minute in pandas. 
[image]
IF there is any value of date is within the last minute i should get it else not.

I am using the below code and its not giving me any error but its returning the expected value.

```
import datetime
created_time = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)
old_objects = data[data['Date'] > created_time]
```

I am getting the below values 
[image]

but i should only get the below :-
[image]

Comment: Can you `print(created_time)`? What do you see?

Comment: I am getting the current time value like this Timestamp('2018-10-17 11:57:37.214967')

Comment: You get the current time and not time minus 1 minute?

Comment: sorry yes i am getting -1 value datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 17, 11, 59, 47, 462484)

Comment: i get the twitter time is in different zone and y zone is different and that is why its happenign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
created_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)

data = data[(data['Date'] > created_time) & (data['Date'] <datetime.datetime.utcnow())]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to limit the range of dates using:

```
old_objects = data[(data['Date'] > created_time) & (data['Date'] < datetime.datetime.now())]
```

I remade your tests and it worked correctly here.

Comment: this is you are getting data for the last 60 sec from now... right?

Comment: Yes, as you had asked. Also, pay attention to the time zone, as @jpp already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You *should* use consistent timezones. And you *should* use Pandas `datetime` objects with Pandas data. You can ensure consistency by using [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`tz_convert`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.dt.tz_convert.html) and [`pd.Timestamp.utcnow`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Timestamp.utcnow.html):-

So try this:

```
created_time = pd.Timestamp.utcnow() - pd.DateOffset(minutes=1)
data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date']).tz_convert('UTC')
```

Comment: thansk alot but i am getting error like index is not a valid DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex... it means i have to make the  Date column as index

Comment: @ak333, It probably means you have bad data, e.g. try `pd.to_datetime(data['Date'], errors='coerce').tz_convert('UTC')`

Comment: same error.. i checked the dtype and its Date      datetime64[ns]

Comment: @ak333, In that case, I can only suggest you provide a [mcve]. Of course, I can't copy-paste your images to replicate your error.